# Add tag to document from Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

We use Kibana, ElasticSearch and Logstash to monitor the health of production systems.

When fatal errors are logged, then handled by our support staff, **we would like to be able to tag them as "Handled/Fixed" as well as insert a comment, within our Kibana dashboard.**

This way we could set up a dashboard that displays only "Unhandled" errors that haven't been looked at by the support staff. A very basic ticket system, if you will, based on production logs.

Is there any plugin for Kibana that provides this feature?

If not, could a gentle soul provide a high-level overview of the development that would be required to write such a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

I would think you could do this with a Javascript file that gets included in the Kibana dashboard.

You would write a file (let's pretend it's called support.js) and then add the  to the Kibana HTML.

Then you can inspect the DOM that Kibana generates and:

1. Add a button where needed.
2. Show a modal popup when the button is clicked.
3. Wire up the save button to make AJAX calls to ES. (Marking a ticket as handled/fixed).

The script would introduce new fields to the documents and then it's easy to configure Kibana to filter on the fields.

That's the most orthogonal way to try and add functionality without getting into the actual Kibana code.